# rvest::set_values() returning error

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to use the `set_values()` function to insert a company name using this website: 
https://www.unternehmensregister.de/ureg/search1.4.html

Unfortunately, after

```
search <- html_form(read_html("https://www.unternehmensregister.de/ureg/search1.4.html"))[[1]]
```

the command

```
set_values(search, searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName - "Daimler")
```

gives an error.

> Error in
>   set_values(search,searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName -
>   :    object 'searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName' not
>   found

It would be great if someone can help me with that!

Comment: Error in set_values(search,searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName -  : 
  object 'searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName' not found

Comment: You need to use quotes because your lhs is not a valid R name. Additionally, `-` should be `=`. `set_values(search,      "searchRegisterForm:companyPublicationsCompanyName" = "Daimler")`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! Now it's fine.